# How can I add a task, which runs a specific .bat, which is located in the folder of the opened source file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am setting up my first task in VS Code. I want to run a .bat file. This is located in the same folder as the source code which is opened in VS Code.

```
./source1/code1.cpp
./source1/code2.cpp
./source1/test.bat


./source2/code1.cpp
./source2/code2.cpp
./source2/test.bat
```

So when I am working on ./source2/code1.cpp I want to run the task on ./source2/test.bat

The error I face is that VS Code tries to run the test.bat in the folder of tasks.json.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "group":"build",
            "options": {
                "cwd":"${fileDirname}"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "call ${cwd}\\test.bat"

        }

    } 
 ]
```

Terminal error output:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (call:Stri
   ng) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

> Executing task: call X:\Folder\To\tasks.json\test.bat <
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{
   "label": "Build",
   "type": "shell",
   "group":"build",
   "windows": {
      "command": "${fileDirname}\\test.bat"
   }
}
```

The test.bat file that is in the same directory as the currently opened file will be called.